# PhpStorm Debug Web Application using Browser

Tags: php, phpstorm

Need some help here.

I have set XDebug and specified the following in my `php.ini`:

```
[Xdebug]
zend_extension="c:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.0\ext\php_xdebug-2.1.2-5.3-vc6.dll"
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_port=9002
xdebug.profiler_enable=1
xdebug.profiler_output_dir="c:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.0"
```

I have configured the PHP in PhpStorm which shows XDEBUG and changed the port to 9002 in the debug settings.

When I debug my web application using browser it says
"Waiting for incoming connection with session id '11390'"

I have setup the web application configuration for the debug specifying my start login page on the server.

But it seems to work fine if I do a debug using console. But debug using console doesn't open the HTML in browser.

Can someone please help with debugging using browser?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have a look at these articles first: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Debugging+with+PhpStorm . If you will still have issues -- post details -- better screencast with your settings and actions.

Comment: Added pictures. Please advise

Comment: 1) Please show header of `phpinfo();` output (captured via browser) + xdebug specific section 2) what xdebug log has to say about this? https://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings#remote_log

Comment: 3) You have ticked "Use path mappings" .. but did not specified any. Either specify or untick it.

Comment: added phpinfo. I dont see a XDDEBUG section, not sure why because if you can see above the PHP.ini i specified has XDEBUG.
I have also unchecked the use "path mappings"

Comment: 1) That table is incomplete -- the info I'm after should be at the end, where ZEND ENGINE logo is etc (it's a separate block just after the table but before the actual configuration) 2) I need xdebug section -- it must be there. If you do not have it .. then you most likely do not have xdebug enabled/working here.

Comment: so looking at the phpinfo i see that it loaded the php.ini from C:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.2.11\bin\php.ini even though i specfied the php.ini from the php folder instead of the apache folder. Anyways i went and added the XDebug in the apache folder php.ini file and it has started working now!!! The real question now is that why is it looking at the php.ini file in the apache folder instead of the php.ini file in the PHP folder

Comment: Because that is how your WAMP configured it. In most Linux distribs as well as MAMP (for Mac) PHP will use different php.ini files -- one for CLI and one for Apache. There is no PhpStorm fault here by any means.